# Posting twitter updates using basic authentication not working

Tags: twitter

I've tried a couple of ways (http://emmense.com/php-twitter/ and http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/04/05/post-to-twitter-from-a-php-script/) to post updates to my twitter account but I am getting the response:

*Basic authentication is not supported*

I had a look at the twitter website and they said something about the new OAuth for authentication. Is this why my code isn't working?

Does anyone know of some PHP code that works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct. They recently adopted OAuth as their sole login platform for 3rd party apps as a security precaution.

Check out their developer area for examples:

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554657/OAuth-Examples

Answer (score 1):

Basic auth is deprecated now. Check out this library https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth for using OAuth in your application

Answer (score 1):

It took me several hours to create this [PHP script](http://all4developer.blogspot.rs/2013/03/twitter-api-11-tutorial.html) but it is working. Just make sure that your hosting company supports cURL. If you don't need the geo features you can cut them out.

Comment: Hey Mike, followed your tutorial you wrote. It looks like twitter has changed the layout and a few things and I think I did everything correctly however it's not posting to twitter. Is there anyway I can view a debug or result to see what part of my script is going wrong?

Comment: Check if Twitter API service is down.